# Bad implementation of back propagation

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm trying to code a neural network in python from scratch but i have problem implementing the backpropagation. I think i understood most of the math behind it but i guess i've missed something because i can't do it. I've tried different code that i found on internet too but nothing seem to work. I would apreciate if someone  could give me advices or point me in the right direction.

Here's my code :

```
 def backpropagation(self,x,y):
    # Place x in input
    self.layers[0].input(x)
    # feed forward 
    y_hat = self.feed_forward()
    for i in reversed(range(len(self.layers))):
        layer = self.layers[i]
        if layer == self.layers[-1]:
            error = y_hat - y
            layer.input_delta = error * self.activation_derivative(y_hat,layer.activation())
        else:
            next_layer = self.layers[i + 1]
            error = np.dot(next_layer.weight(), next_layer.delta())
            layer.input_delta = error * self.activation_derivative(layer.output(),layer.activation())

    for i in range(len(self.layers)):
        layer = self.layers[i]
        layer.input_weight += layer.delta() * self._alpha
```

And here's my error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 Model.compile(train_data=(X_train,y_train_2),lr = 1 ,validation=(X_test,y_test_2),epoch = 20,batch = 10)

 in compile(self, train_data, lr, validation, epoch, batch)
     40 
     41                 for x, y in zip(X_train,y_train):
---> 42                     self.backpropagation(x,y)
     43 
     44                 True_result = 0

 in backpropagation(self, x, y)
     28             else:
     29                 next_layer = self.layers[i + 1]
---> 30                 error = np.dot(layer.weight(), next_layer.delta())
     31                 layer.input_delta = error * self.activation_derivative(layer.output(),layer.activation())
     32 

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (4,4) and (2,2) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

And the summary of the layer i use in this exemple

```
Input layers input : 2
Hidden_layer input : 2 ouput : 4 activation function : Relu 
Hidden_layer input : 4 ouput : 4 activation function : Relu 
Output_layer input : 4 ouput : 2 activation function : Softmax
```

Activation function

```
 def activation(self,x,activation):
        if(activation == "Relu"):
            return x * (x > 0)
        elif(activation == "Softmax"):
            e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x)) 
        return e_x / e_x.sum(axis=0) 

 def activation_derivative(self,x,activation):
        if(activation == "Relu"):
            x[x<=0] = 0
            x[x>0] = 1
            return   x
        elif(activation == "Softmax"):
            deriv = x.reshape(-1,1)
            return np.diagflat(deriv) - np.dot(deriv, deriv.T)
```

Comment: The layer.weight() and next_layer.delta() have not the same size. You probably mess with the calculation of this two parameters after the "relu" activation. Check the formulation of BP and your implementation.

Comment: I've checked the activation function again and i don't think the problem is there :/